# My keyboard symbols suddenly changed

Tags: keyboard, keys

My keyboard symbols suddenly changed. For example, if I type the backslash key, it gives #, if I use shift + 2, it gives " instead of @. I don't understand what has changed suddenly. Does anybody know how to get this back to normal?

I've tried lots of things: changing the language of the keyboard, restarting the computer, various key combinations, num lock. Nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check under Settings>>Keyboard. Your layout has been changed to some EU layout.

Comment: I can't find how to change it back. Should it be changed back to US?

Comment: There should be an option somewhere there to change the layout back to US.

Comment: Yeah I tried System settings, text entry and changed it to US there, nothing happened though, not even after restarting.

Comment: Is there a keyboard button (or any new icon) in the top bar on the desktop?

Comment: Yeah!! That solves it!! Thanks!! Such a simple problem, but so annoying if you can't find the solution for so long.

Comment: It is. Did you install anything new recently that might have changed the layout?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Maybe I accidentally clicked the button. There is indeed a button in the top bar of the desktop with which you can very easily change the keyboard layout between UK and US.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be there unless someone/thing added a new keyboard layout. It's definitely weird.

Comment: Yeah indeed, extra frustrating that it happened suddenly while I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your keyboard layout was somehow changed, I think to the UK layout.

There should be an icon in the status/menu bar that looks like a keyboard, or is a rectangle with a country code inside. Click that icon and you'll be able to select the US layout.

Answer (score 3):

So I faced a similar issue. I was able to fix it in the following way:

1. Spot the word "ENG" in the task/menu bar at the bottom of the screen.(for me it was right beside where it shows the time and date).
2. Click on the "ENG" symbol.
3. From the options that pop up, choose which ever is the alternative to "English (United Kingdom) United Kingdom.Keyboard".

In my case the alternative was "English (India)", clicking on it helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In  Setting section you can find one Language and Region option.
there you can Update language in "Input sources" and issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go inside the Setting and navigate to the "Region & Language", where you can see the Language and format you have selected. From the input sources, you can add different languages and on clicking on the preview (eye) button you can see what operation each button will perform.
[Keyboard Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3CNr.png)

Setting -> Region & Language -> Input Sources