# Superkey suddenly changed behaviour and acts as a CTRL-key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My Superkey/Win-key suddenly changed its behaviour and is now a second ctrl-key. I did not do anything to change it. At least not intentionally.

How to change it back to the original behavior?

Additional Info:

Ubuntu Version 18.10

Output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` is `['grp_led:scroll']`

Output of `xmodmap -pke | grep Control`

```
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L NoSymbol Control_L Control_L
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R NoSymbol Control_R Control_R
```

Output of `xmodmap -pke | grep Super`

```
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R NoSymbol Super_R Super_R
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
```

Output of `xev` pressing and releasing physical Superkey(winkey).

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` and what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ok, can you also post the output of `xmodmap -pke | grep Control` `xmodmap -pke | grep Super`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional infos.. as of now.. infos seems nothing different.. now run `xev` command and then hit Physical Key Super/ Windows and post the output.. like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyFz0.png

Comment: Hi, are you sure.. you pressed physical key with the windows logo while running `xev` command? I doubt you press Ctrl key with Ctrl written on the key

Comment: If you are 100% sure that when pressing Superkey/ Windows key you got the output of keycode 37 = Control_L you can remap this key to Super/Windows keysym by running this command in terminal `xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L Super_L"` like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq8PF.png

Comment: also please have a look on this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/764636/739431

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, I am 100% sure I pressed the superkey. I just tested it again and the output of when pressing the physical superkey and the output when pressing the physical L Control key is identical. Thus, when I remap like you suggested, my L Control will be Superkey, too, right?

Comment: no, what i suggested is only to change the keycode 37 that is physical Super/ Windows key.. my suggestion dont deal with other key functionality..

Comment: you dont need to worry about running the command in terminal `xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L Super_L"` this will not be effective after a logout or reboot... but you can make this permanent if you wish with few additional steps.. even after making permenent you can revert back to the normal situation before this question is asked with few steps..

Comment: @PRATAP Well, that disbelief in pressing the pressing the correct button made me connect another keyboard. Then it worked. Therefor I checked my original keyboard again and it turns out it has a "Disable" Window key button/function which I did not knew off and which was turned on. Turning it off solved the issue. Thanks. You want to post that as an anwser and I can flag it as such?

Comment: Oh great! you made it, you can post the solution..Thank You..

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, as often the case, in front of the monitor. :-)
My keyboard, TT esports Poseidon ZX, has a key to turn off the Superkey(winkey), which I did not knew about.

After toggling it again and turnin off the functionality everything worked as expected again.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.